# Click Handler in Builder cannot be applied to void

Tags: litho, facebook-litho

I am working in mobile application (android) and  start to learn litho framework, I write a click handler for particular widget inside component. But the error is displayed

> "Builder cannot be applied to void" why this issue is came for a reason?

How to resolve that issue. I need another issue. how   to retrieve the text input value Thanks for your response

```
package com.hotfoot.rapid.aubank.sbl.fragment.qde;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.Layout;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import com.facebook.litho.Border;
import com.facebook.litho.ClickEvent;
import com.facebook.litho.Column;
import com.facebook.litho.Component;
import com.facebook.litho.ComponentContext;
import com.facebook.litho.Handle;
import com.facebook.litho.annotations.LayoutSpec;
import com.facebook.litho.annotations.OnCreateLayout;
import com.facebook.litho.annotations.OnEvent;
import com.facebook.litho.annotations.Param;
import com.facebook.litho.annotations.Prop;
import com.facebook.litho.widget.Text;
import com.facebook.litho.widget.TextInput;
import com.facebook.yoga.YogaEdge;
import com.hotfoot.rapid.au.msme.app.pojo.caf.Assessment;
import com.hotfoot.rapid.aubank.sbl.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@LayoutSpec
public class CAFAssessmentListItem {

  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
  @OnCreateLayout
  static Component onCreateLayout(
      ComponentContext c,
      CAFAssessmentFragment cafFragment,
      Assessment assessment,
      @Prop String n) {
    List<String> districtNames = new ArrayList();
    districtNames.add("Chennai");
    districtNames.add("Erode");
    districtNames.add("Coimbatore");
    districtNames.add("Tirunelveli");

    final Handle textInputHandle = new Handle();

    return Column.create(c)
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.ro_assessment))
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_LEFT)
                .textSizeSp(18.0f)
                .textStyle(1)
                .textColor(
                    cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.input_text_color)))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("CUSTOMER NAME")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .textSizeSp(12.0f)
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color)))
        .child(
            TextInput.create(c)
                .hint("")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
                .background(
                    cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_apply_line))
                .multiline(false)
                .maxLines(1))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("CUSTOMER ADDRESS")
                .paddingDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 1.0f)
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .textSizeSp(12.0f)
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color)))
        .child(
            TextInput.create(c)
                .hint("")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
                .multiline(true)
                .maxLines(5)
                .background(
                    cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_edt_popup)))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("CUSTOMER CONTACT NO")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .textSizeSp(12.0f)
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color)))
        .child(
            TextInput.create(c)
                .hint("")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE)
                .background(
                    cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_apply_line))
                .multiline(false)
                .maxLines(1))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("CUSTOMER BUSINESS")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .textSizeSp(12.0f)
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color)))
        .child(
            TextInput.create(c)
                .hint("")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
                .background(
                    cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_apply_line))
                .multiline(false)
                .maxLines(1))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("LOAN AMOUNT APPLIED")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .textSizeSp(12.0f)
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color)))
        .child(
            TextInput.create(c)
                .hint("")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
                .background(
                    cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_apply_line))
                .multiline(false)
                .maxLines(1))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("TENURE")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .textSizeSp(12.0f)
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color)))
        .child(
            TextInput.create(c)
                .hint("")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
                .background(
                    cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_apply_line))
                .multiline(false)
                .maxLines(1))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("EMi")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .textSizeSp(12.0f)
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color)))
        .child(
            TextInput.create(c)
                .hint("")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
                .background(
                    cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_apply_line))
                .multiline(false)
                .maxLines(1))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("PD WITH")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .textSizeSp(12.0f)
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color)))
        .child(
            com.facebook.litho.widget.Spinner.create(c)
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .options(districtNames)
                .selectedOption(districtNames.get(1))
                .border(
                    Border.create(c)
                        .widthDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 1)
                        .color(YogaEdge.ALL, Color.BLACK)
                        .build()))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("PLACE OF PD-ADDRESS")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .textSizeSp(12.0f)
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color)))
        .child(
            com.facebook.litho.widget.Spinner.create(c)
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .options(districtNames)
                .selectedOption(districtNames.get(1))
                .border(
                    Border.create(c)
                        .widthDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 1)
                        .color(YogaEdge.ALL, Color.BLACK)
                        .build()))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("PURPOSE OF LOAN")
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .textSizeSp(12.0f)
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color)))
        .child(
            com.facebook.litho.widget.Spinner.create(c)
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .options(districtNames)
                .selectedOption(districtNames.get(1))
                .border(
                    Border.create(c)
                        .widthDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 1)
                        .color(YogaEdge.ALL, Color.BLACK)
                        .build()))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("SAVE")
                .textSizeSp(14.0f)
                .paddingDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 12.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER)
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .backgroundColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.orange))
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
                .border(
                    Border.create(c)
                        .widthDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 1)
                        .color(YogaEdge.ALL, Color.parseColor("#F36F21"))
                        .build()))
        .child(
            Text.create(c)
                .text("NEXT")
                .textSizeSp(14.0f)
                .paddingDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 12.0f)
                .textAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER)
                .marginDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 10.0f)
                .backgroundColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.purple))
                .textColor(cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
                .border(
                    Border.create(c)
                        .widthDip(YogaEdge.ALL, 1)
                        .color(YogaEdge.ALL, Color.parseColor("#FFA500"))
                        .build()))
        .clickHandler(CAFAssessmentListItem.onEditTextClick(c, textInputHandle))
        .build();
  }

  @OnEvent(ClickEvent.class)
  static void onEditTextClick(ComponentContext c, @Param Handle textInputHandle) {
    String customer = TextInput.getText(c, textInputHandle).toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your LayoutSpec class's name is supposed to end with `Spec` and you should not ever call its methods directly.
When your Spec class will be named `MyComponentSpec` the compiler will generate a real Litho Component implementation named `MyComponent` (notice the absence of the suffix `Spec`). And methods of this class you are supposed to use. I.e, in your example you reference `CAFAssessmentListItem.onEditTextClick(c, textInputHandle)` which is `Spec`'s method (which you wrote manually), but you should use Component's method (which will be generated by the compiler).

Second, all inputs to the component should be marked as `@Prop`, i.e `@Prop Assessment assessment`. Again, because you should not use `onCreateLayout` method yourself – you'll use generated ComponentBuilder. Like:

```
CAFAssessmentListItem.create(c)
  .assessment(myAssessment)
  .n(myString)
  .build()
```

Third, you don't need your fragment to retrieve resources. There are specific methods for this, i.e

```
Text.create(c)
  .testRes(resId)
  .textColorRes(colorResId)
  .backgroundColorRes(colorResId2)
```

Fourth, you've never bound `textInputHandle` with the `TextInput` widget to get anything on the `onClick`. Check out this doc: https://fblitho.com/docs/trigger-events. You need to add `.handle(textInputHandle)` to the `TextInput`.

And lastly, you don't need to parse color from string `.color(Color.parseColor("#F36F21"))` when you already have the value for that color – you can just use hexadecimal int `.color(0xFFF36F21)`.

To sum it up:

1. Rename your class, add `Spec` to the end (but don't rename `CAFAssessmentListItem.onEditTextClick` invocation).
2. Add `@Prop` to `Assessment` param and remove Fragment param from `onCreateLayout`
3. Replace `cafFragment.getActivity().getResources().` calls to just using resource Ids and respective methods in widgets
4. Add `.handle(textInputHandle)` to the `TextInput` widget
5. Cleanup setting color values

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.I need an explanation about the error "Builder cannot be applied to void"

Comment: @MuthukumarS sure check out this part of my  answer:

`in your example you reference CAFAssessmentListItem.onEditTextClick(c, textInputHandle) which is Spec's method (which you wrote manually), but you should use Component's method (which will be generated by the compiler).`

I.e method you use doesn't return `Builder` it returns `void`